# Getting an error(MESSAGE A handler conflict occurred. This may disable some commands) when launching eclipse

Tags: eclipse-pde

I developed one plugin(RMP) in eclipse 3.3.2 where i am creating menu items dynamically. I ran the application and it is working fine and am able to see the menu items created dynamically.

Now I exported this plugin(RMP).  I added this in plugin folder of eclipse 3.4 installation. Now I launched eclipse and I am able to see all the functionalities implemented in my plugin(RMP) but the menu items created dynamically are invisible. When i click on menu, nothing is coming.
Pls find the error log below for more information. I took this log from my `workspace -> .metadata` folder.

```
Log:
!ENTRY org.eclipse.ui.workbench 2 0 2009-03-30 11:59:23.266
!MESSAGE A handler conflict occurred.  This may disable some commands.
!SUBENTRY 1 org.eclipse.ui.workbench 2 0 2009-03-30 11:59:23.267
!MESSAGE Conflict for 'AUTODCTOOL':
HandlerActivation(commandId=AUTODCTOOL,
    handler=ActionDelegateHandlerProxy(null,com.ericsson.eadt.apstoolsintegrator.actions.APSToolAction),
    expression=AndExpression(ActionSetExpression(APSToolsIntegrator.APSSystemFullSet,org.eclipse.ui.internal.WorkbenchWindow@166c114),WorkbenchWindowExpression(org.eclipse.ui.internal.WorkbenchWindow@166c114)),sourcePriority=16640)
HandlerActivation(commandId=AUTODCTOOL,
    handler=ActionDelegateHandlerProxy(null,com.ericsson.eadt.apstoolsintegrator.actions.APSToolAction),
    expression=AndExpression(ActionSetExpression(APSToolsIntegrator.APSSystemFullSet,org.eclipse.ui.internal.WorkbenchWindow@166c114),WorkbenchWindowExpression(org.eclipse.ui.internal.WorkbenchWindow@166c114)),sourcePriority=16640)
!SUBENTRY 1 org.eclipse.ui.workbench 2 0 2009-03-30 11:59:23.267
!MESSAGE Conflict for 'BTIDRIVER':
HandlerActivation(commandId=BTIDRIVER,
    handler=ActionDelegateHandlerProxy(null,com.ericsson.eadt.apstoolsintegrator.actions.APSToolAction),
    expression=AndExpression(ActionSetExpression(APSToolsIntegrator.APSSystemFullSet,org.eclipse.ui.internal.WorkbenchWindow@166c114),WorkbenchWindowExpression(org.eclipse.ui.internal.WorkbenchWindow@166c114)),sourcePriority=16640)
HandlerActivation(commandId=BTIDRIVER,
    handler=ActionDelegateHandlerProxy(null,com.ericsson.eadt.apstoolsintegrator.actions.APSToolAction),
    expression=AndExpression(ActionSetExpression(APSToolsIntegrator.APSSystemFullSet,org.eclipse.ui.internal.WorkbenchWindow@166c114),WorkbenchWindowExpression(org.eclipse.ui.internal.WorkbenchWindow@166c114)),sourcePriority=16640)
```

Requesting help in this regard,
Thanks in advance.

Snehal.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try launching your eclipse3.4 with the `-clean` option.

If a `-clean` is not enough, the problem lies in the definition of `com.ericsson.eadt.apstoolsintegrator.actions.APSToolAction`.

If it is an [action set](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/552435/eclipse-rcp-actions-vs-commands), check its definition: a keybinding used might be in conflict with legacy eclipse3.4 keys definition.