# CTRL+click to open method declaration doesn't work on Eclipse 3.5 (Galileo)

Tags: java, eclipse, galileo

In a J2EE project Ctrl+click on methods (usually only local methods, ones that belong to the same class) doesn't jump to that method declaration. 
The eclipse project was created using Gradle so that might be an issue, also when Eclipse starts the log has the following exception:

> A handler conflict occurred.  This may disable some commands. 
>   Conflict for 'org.eclipse.wst.jsdt.ui.edit.text.java.open.editor':HandlerActivation(commandId=org.eclipse.wst.jsdt.ui.edit.text.java.open.editor,
>   handler=ActionHandler(org.eclipse.wst.jsdt.ui.actions.OpenAction@c5f6db),
>   expression=AndExpression(AndExpression(org.eclipse.ui.SubActionBars$1@fdd15b,ActivePartExpression(org.eclipse.ui.navigator.resources.ProjectExplorer@38ba04)),WorkbenchWindowExpression(org.eclipse.ui.internal.WorkbenchWindow@1f528ab)),sourcePriority=1064961)
>   HandlerActivation(commandId=org.eclipse.wst.jsdt.ui.edit.text.java.open.editor,
>   handler=ActionHandler(org.eclipse.wst.jsdt.ui.actions.OpenAction@c5f6db),
>   expression=AndExpression(AndExpression(org.eclipse.ui.SubActionBars$1@fdd15b,ActivePartExpression(org.eclipse.ui.navigator.resources.ProjectExplorer@38ba04)),WorkbenchWindowExpression(org.eclipse.ui.internal.WorkbenchWindow@1f528ab)),sourcePriority=1064961)

I am running eclipse on Fedora 12 distro

Comment: Does http://stackoverflow.com/questions/696887/getting-an-errormessage-a-handler-conflict-occurred-this-may-disable-some-comm help?

Comment: Not really, or I can't see how

Comment: Did you install it from a zip file or through the Fedorapackage system

Comment: It can happen some times, just try restarting your eclipse. It should work.

Answer (score 7):

it seems you didn't put the source code into your classpath.
just right click you source code package and select "build path -> use as source folder"

Comment: For pydev project "PyDev -> Set as source folder"

Answer (score 6):

I could always just press F3.

Comment: Yes that works, but less desired :)

Comment: cnotrol + click is way more popular

Answer (score 1):

If your code contains error it will not let you to do ctrl+click to see the defination so...
try to remove the errors first

Comment: I am using `indigo` I removed a `}` from my file and did `ctrl+click` on any method which was underlined `red` but it did take me to the defination of that method. Is that what you are trying to say wont happen?