# How to use viewActions with Commands?

Tags: java, eclipse-rcp

I've learned that actions in Eclipse-RCP should not be used and instead commands should be used.

The problem is if I try to use the ExtensionPoint org.eclipse.ui.viewActions(makes little icons on top of views, see Image) only Actions can be defined there.

[image]
<sub>(source: [eclipse.org](http://help.eclipse.org/stable/topic/org.eclipse.platform.doc.isv/guide/images/readmeviewaction.png))</sub>

Is there a way to use commands with this ExtensionPoint?

If that is not possible, is it possible to execute a command from an action?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I've got it.

You can use the org.eclipse.ui.menus extension point and add a new menuContribution with locationURI: "toolbar:yourViewId".

To this menu you can add commands and they will behave like the org.eclipse.ui.viewActions actions.

Comment: I would like to do the same with editorActions but i cannot find a way to add "editorActions" via org.eclipse.ui.menus extension point. you have any idea how to do that?

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in my answer [Eclipse RCP: Actions VS Commands](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/552435/eclipse-rcp-actions-vs-commands), there are command extension points.

[Command extension points http://www.vogella.de/articles/RichClientPlatform/images/command40.gif](http://www.vogella.de/articles/RichClientPlatform/images/command40.gif)

I would recommand using those instead of action extension points.

Comment: I don't understand your answer. Is there a command extension that creates the same behaviour as org.eclipse.ui.viewActions does?