# How do you contribute a command to an editor context menu in Eclipse

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin

I want to contribute a command to the context menu of any text editor when text is selected. In "the old days", I would have done this using objectContribution and a nested action with "enablesFor='+'".

How does one do this using commands instead of actions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I read more about the variables available in command expressions, and I came *close* to figuring it out on my own, but failed. I then asked a similar question on the eclipse newsgroup and was led in the right direction. Here's an example of how to do mostly what I was looking for:

```
 <command
      commandId="org.marcesher.blogcodeformatter.commands.wikiFormatterCommand"
      tooltip="Format And Copy to Clipboard"
      id="org.marcesher.blogcodeformatter.popup.wikiFormatterCommand">
    <visibleWhen>
       <with variable="selection">
          <instanceof value="org.eclipse.jface.text.ITextSelection"/>
       </with>
    </visibleWhen>
```

Answer (score 2):

If I revisit my answer "[Eclipse RCP: Actions VS Commands](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/552435/eclipse-rcp-actions-vs-commands)", you need a Command handler.

[This thread](http://dev.eclipse.org/newslists/news.eclipse.platform/msg77651.html) seems to sum up your options:

> - One is a common pattern, to instantiate the handler in the view itself and have the handler simply look at the view selection and control its own enabled state.
>     The handler API allows it to fire an event on enabled change, see [`org.eclipse.core.commands.AbstractHandler`](http://kickjava.com/src/org/eclipse/core/commands/AbstractHandler.java.htm).
> - The other is to create a property tester that can get your view selection.

```
IWorkbenchPart p = page.findViewReference("your.id").getPart(false);
if (p!=null) {
  p.getSite().getSelectionProvider().getSelection() ... whatever
}
```

> Your view would monitor its own selection change events, and call [`org.eclipse.ui.services.IEvaluationService.requestEvaluation(String)`](http://help.eclipse.org/stable/index.jsp?topic=/org.eclipse.platform.doc.isv/reference/api/org/eclipse/ui/services/IEvaluationService.html) (source [here](http://www.java2s.com/Open-Source/Java-Document/IDE-Eclipse/ui-workbench/org/eclipse/ui/internal/services/IEvaluationService.java.htm)) for that property (which would cause all core expressions using that property tester to be re-evaluated).
>   The important point is that simply changing views would not cause a re-evaluation (and not change enabled state).
>
> You can set up the property tester to be specific to each view that you need this for, or create one `com.example.views.localSelection` and use `args` to specify the view `id`.

Comment: Thanks VonC. So looking at this, I can see no benefit to doing this with commands vs. objectContributions and Actions. Thoughts?

Comment: If the `Command`/`handler` is not reused in many editors/views, it can be a little overkill and a single `Action` is enough.