# How to control Context Menu for EditorView in Eclipse?

Tags: eclipse-rcp, eclipse-plugin

I am trying to control the visibility of context menu items for EditorView in Eclipse. Here is the plugin configuration code

```
<visibleWhen>
   <with  variable="activeEditorId">
      <equals value="org.eclipse.ui.DefaultTextEditor"></equals>
   </with>
</visibleWhen>
```

but somehow it is not working and not showing the menu item for editor at all. Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: Is org.eclipse.ui.DefaultTextEditor the correct id value for Java Editor view? That's I need to know...

Answer (score 0):

Can you try with `org.eclipse.jdt.ui.CompilationUnitEditor`?

Comment: Thanks, but No luck yet! I imported the org.eclipse.jdt.ui to the project also..any other idea?

Comment: Got it. here it is http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1356798/how-do-you-contribute-a-command-to-an-editor-context-menu-in-eclipse?rq=1