# Printing with an Eclipse RCP program

Tags: java, eclipse, printing, eclipse-rcp, rcp

I am looking for a good, standard way to generate "output" in my RCP programm and print it. This should work as it works on Windows, Mac OS and Linux with the standard print dialog.

I am aware of the Birt project, but I could not find any hints about how to implement it within a RCP programm and how to invoke the standard print dialog and how to pass the Birt generated report to the printer.

Happy for all hints.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe the Birt [project used to use IText](http://www.eclipse.org/birt/build/install.html). (now [ITextPDF](http://itextpdf.com/))

The other solution is to [integrate Apache Fop in your RCP project](http://dev.eclipse.org/newslists/news.eclipse.platform.rcp/msg11948.html). (see [Apache FOP](http://xmlgraphics.apache.org/fop/)).
For that to work, [it is advised to](http://mail-archives.apache.org/mod_mbox//xmlgraphics-fop-dev/200811.mbox/%3C20081113200424.5F7A.60BA733C@jeremias-maerki.ch%3E) not implement a renderer
but implement a `IFDocumentHandler`/`IFPainter` pair, as part of a new intermediate format (if that has been integrated to Fop, which I am not sure):

- create a new Java project, decide on a
  package name and prepare two classes implementing `IFDocumentHandler`
  (document-level) and `IFPainter` (page-level).
  These interfaces are found in the package `org.apache.fop.render.intermediate`.
- To register the new implementation, you need to define a MIME type (see also
  `MimeConstants.java`) and create a class extending `AbstractIFDocumentHandlerMaker` which serves as a factory class.
- Then create a text file called `META-INF/services/org.apache.fop.render.intermediate.IFDocumentHandler` in which you write the fully qualified class name of that "maker" class.
- One thing I may have to add (that is currently- missing) is a `setIFDocumentHandlerOverride()` method in `FOUserAgent`, so you can set up the output in an `SWT` window. The normal API is optimized for generating files.

---

The [bug 23618](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=23618) (fixed seven years later!) contains a small example of making a Printer Job, and the [SWT FAQ](http://www.eclipse.org/swt/faq.php#installedprinters) has some interesting elements on Printer (vs. Display, DPI and Trim). This [SWT snippet](http://www.java2s.com/Code/Java/SWT-JFace-Eclipse/PrintDialogExample.htm) is quite clear too.
However, none of those examples are called through commands, even though you can [define one easily](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/552435/eclipse-rcp-actions-vs-commands/552450#552450)) once you have a Handler (i.e. any class you wrote, able to open the print dialog) set up.

Note: be aware, when you are calling the Print Dialog Box, that only the very latest releases of Eclipse Helios 3.6 (namely the [3.6M5 of late January 2010](http://download.eclipse.org/eclipse/downloads/drops/S-3.6M5-201001291300/eclipse-news-M5.html)) is able to  remember the user selected options for all textual editors until the workbench is shutdown (that is:

- Selected printer
- Print to file
- Printer preferences: These are printer specific options like paper size, page order orientation etc. )

Comment: Thanks, sounds like a very good answer. Just the link to my eclipse RCP program and the standard print dialog is unclear to me. And how is the output "moved" to the printer(queue).

Comment: Thanks again, but it seems like we are talking about 2 different things. I wanted to understand how to call and use a standard print dialog (using commands, not actions - since actions should be used anymore..) and then how to get the data passed to the printerqueue. Havent found tutorials about that yet.

Comment: @Raven: true, that was an old FAQ entry based on actions, which is "bad";) I have updated my answer with some elements on the topic, but without definitive answers though.

Answer (score 0):

You might consider using SWT Paperclips.  This made printing from my RCP application much, much easier.

http://code.google.com/p/swt-paperclips/