# Eclipse RCP: Actions vs Commands - would like an update

Tags: java, eclipse, eclipse-rcp

I know [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/552435/462285) has been asked before but it was in 2009 and I haven't found anything more recent either on the web. I was wondering if the answer in that still holds or can it be updated?

I am just starting work on an RCP and I haven't been able to decide between actions and commands for my menu items. I will be using a lot of the ones provided by Eclipse such as the Edit, File and some of their sub menu items as well. Since it has been nearly two years for the answer provided in the '09 question, I just wanted to make sure there is nothing else that could sway my decision in either direction or maybe if there have been some new developments that I am not aware of.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Since you are starting on RCP the Command Framework is the way to go. Actions are depcrecated and you should only have to use when working with existing applications.

Answer (score 0):

Commnads framework is best. You can easily control the visibility of menues using commands.