# The way of access to Actions in Eclipse rcp development

Tags: java, eclipse, eclipse-rcp

I am wondering to know if there is any way of access to Actions, ActionBar 
o ActionBarAdvisor, once they are created and registered.

Thanks
Joseph

Comment: Are you developping a new project ? If so, the use of `Actions` is discouraged and you should use `Commands`. You should read [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/552435/eclipse-rcp-actions-vs-commands)

Comment: Yes. I am developing my first rcp application. I searched out your mentioned thread. In my current implementation, I use actions to add some menus.

Comment: You can do that using `Commands` too :) Look these pages : [1](http://www.vogella.com/articles/EclipseCommands/article.html) [2](http://wiki.eclipse.org/Platform_Command_Framework)

Answer (score 0):

In your rcp app class that extends ActionBarAdvisor you can create a static reference to what you need to in the the method protected void fillCoolBar(ICoolBarManager coolBar) {